# Error loading RecyclerView from FirebaseUI

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebaseui

Im having problems integrating a RecyclerView into my App.

Its throwing me this exception

```
05-17 16:47:40.866 32761-32761/com.isdsw.infinitytv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.isdsw.infinitytv, PID: 32761
                                                                  com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
                                                                      at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
                                                                      at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:161)
                                                                      at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:150)
                                                                      at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:190)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1993)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1482)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$400(RecyclerView.java:147)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:294)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "-KHvEl9amJFCS7CREZD2" (class com.isdsw.infinitytv.stream.data.StreamData), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: , "custom", "online", "condition", "image", "id", "info"])
                                                                      at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7c8eb8c; line: 1, column: 26] (through reference chain: com.isdsw.infinitytv.stream.data.StreamData["-KHvEl9amJFCS7CREZD2"])
                                                                      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:555)
                                                                      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:708)
                                                                      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1160)
                                                                      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:315)
                                                                      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
                                                                      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
                                                                      at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
                                                                      at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:181)
                                                                      at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:161) 
                                                                      at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:150) 
                                                                      at com.firebase.ui.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:190) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1993) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1482) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$400(RecyclerView.java:147) 
                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:294) 
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858) 
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603) 
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

05-17 16:52:40.918 32761-32761/com.isdsw.infinitytv I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32761 SIG: 9

This is where i create de adapter

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<StreamData, StreamerViewHolder>(StreamData.class, R.layout.cv_stream, StreamerViewHolder.class, refStreamers) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(StreamerViewHolder streamerViewHolder, StreamData streamData, int i) {
            Log.e("TAG", String.valueOf(mAdapter.getItemCount()));
            streamerViewHolder.name.setText(streamData.getInfo().getName());
            streamerViewHolder.display_name.setText(streamData.getInfo().getDisplay_name());
            streamerViewHolder.game.setText(streamData.getInfo().getGame());
        }
    };
```

and the data object where it apears to break is this one

```
public class StreamData {

private ConditionData condition;

private InfoData info;

private ImageData image;

private CustomData custom;

private String online;

public StreamData(ConditionData condition, InfoData info, ImageData image, CustomData custom, String online) {
    this.condition = condition;
    this.info = info;
    this.image = image;
    this.custom = custom;
    this.online = online;
}

public StreamData() {
}

public ConditionData getCondition() {
    return condition;
}

public void setCondition(ConditionData condition) {
    this.condition = condition;
}

public InfoData getInfo() {
    return info;
}

public void setInfo(InfoData info) {
    this.info = info;
}

public ImageData getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(ImageData image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public CustomData getCustom() {
    return custom;
}

public void setCustom(CustomData custom) {
    this.custom = custom;
}

public String getOnline() {
    return online;
}

public void setOnline(String online) {
    this.online = online;
}
}
```

I heared is a problem with jackson but im new to this type of thing like serialize JSON. If you need any extra information ask me and i will show u :)

EDIT

Added an example of my database object

```
{
"-KHvEl9amJFCS7CREZD2" : {
"condition" : {
  "active" : true,
  "banner" : false,
  "display_name" : true,
  "logo" : false,
  "profile_banner" : false,
  "status" : false,
  "video_banner" : false
},
"custom" : {
  "display_name" : "Prueba",
  "show" : "video_banner",
  "video_banner" : ""
},
"image" : {
  "logo" : "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/misslaia-profile_image-7bc81446a0a045b5-300x300.jpeg",
  "preview_large" : "",
  "preview_medium" : "",
  "preview_small" : "",
  "preview_template" : "",
  "profile_banner" : "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/misslaia-profile_banner-9b043043de1029ad-480.png"
},
"info" : {
  "display_name" : "MissLaia",
  "followers" : 6125,
  "game" : "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
  "name" : "misslaia",
  "status" : "[ESP] CS:GO ◕ ‿‿ ◕  || Giveaway twitter --->  !sorteo",
  "url" : "https://www.twitch.tv/misslaia",
  "views" : 95055
},
"online" : false
}
```

}

Comment: Your `refStreamers` seems to be pointing one level too high in the database.

Comment: Post a little snapshot of your db (not an image please) and your ref

Comment: Ok Thanks i fixed the problem but now i have other problem dont know if u can help me but when i scroll the reciclerview it thorws me this error com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type without saying me wath parametrer is failing